# SiteMap based on user roles doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I have sitemap which looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
   <siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" title="Prva stran" roles="*"  description="Shema ISEF">    
        <siteMapNode roles="2" title="Analize" id="Analize"  description="" >
             <siteMapNode url="~/karneki1.aspx" title="Karneki1"  description="" />
             <siteMapNode url="~/karneki2.aspx" title="Karneki2"  description="" />    
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

if I set roles in a siteMapNode with title "Analiza" it works fine, the link is not shown in the navigation... but if I set roles on any of "karneki" siteMapNode the links are still visible...

Is it even posible to restrict access to lower links based on user role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SiteMap 'securityTrimmingEnabled' attribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx

The asecurityTrimmingEnabled attribute also needs to be added to the nodes in the markup:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx

An overview of how securityTrimmingEnabled is supposed to work:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dannychen/archive/2006/03/16/553005.aspx

Comment: <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider " siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
            </providers>
        </siteMap>

Comment: Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized attribute 'securityTrimmingEnabled'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Comment: OK, i made some progress... roles only work if there is no url attribute in sitemapnode... any clues?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? I remember having a problem with this before in 2.0. Eventually I had to programmatically add a "roles" attribute myself and tie it into my membership system. I had another attribute for "roletype" to distinguish between Active Directory and membership system. Wait a second... try making the "S" in 'securityTrimmingEnabled" capitalized? Let me know if that works first?

Comment: ASP.NET 2.0... I tried with capital S... it didn't show error but it didn't work ether. It still has problems with url=""... if it is not empty the roles don't work...

Comment: is there any way to override this procedure, and to write my own conditions when will the link be shown or not?

Comment: You've set up a membership system and have users and roles?

Comment: I set up my own role provider... anyway i gave up with these sitemap roles.. I wrote my own navigation control so now the roles work perfect. Sorry for wasting your time, and thank you for your help.

Comment: No prob... I had to do the same thing some time back :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment to say I'd tried this and thought it hadn't worked but actually I hadn't implemented it properly. If you have a page in a folder and you want to give access to the folder to groups A + B but access to that page to just group B, in the Web.config, you need to put the folder permissions before the page acess permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is that you need to set the roles in a Web.config for the pages itself.

See http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx

e.g. in the folder for a page called AdminOnly.aspx add a Web.Config with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="AdminOnly.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the roles to the site map like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" roles="*" title="Prva stran" roles="*"  description="Shema ISEF">
    <siteMapNode roles="2" title="Analize" id="Analize"  description="" >
      <siteMapNode roles="*" url="~/karneki1.aspx" title="Karneki1"  description="" />
      <siteMapNode roles="*" url="~/karneki2.aspx" title="Karneki2"  description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```